# How to plot 40GB hspice output?

Tags: matlab, hspice

I don't know other software to plot the file and get results put into the report. Matlab hspice toolbox is good for small size files, but I am not sure it is fine with large size ones.

Can I plot the output file .tr0 with some software? Matlab or others? Is Matlab hspicetoolbox suitable for large size files?

Comment: not screenshot results

Comment: Did you try it? What happened?

Comment: what matlab version do you have?

Comment: the current version I have is R2016b

Answer (score 1):

You can open up sections of a large text file in matlab, you may be able to sub-sample the text data and plot it out. I would propose a different solution. I would reduce the file size first.

Depending on how long the simulation takes. I would only output one signal per file. So if you have hspice recording multiple signals in your output, only do one at a time and store the file and run the simulation multiple times.

Ask yourself if you really need the resolution of the simulation, and reduce it to something more manageable.

I know LTspice will let you set a time for the recording of data after the simulation start time, hspice may also have something like this.

Comment: the text file includes more than 10 subcircuits. my last comment in text file .tran 20ns 15ms
.option post=1
.plot I(cout) I(cload) .end

Comment: How am I gonna put one output signal per file? I have lots of plotting output.

Comment: It shouldn't plot out everything when you do a .plot statement no other spice package does. I'd find a new spice package, hspice was last updated 20 years ago

Comment: It's been a while but you might want .print instead of .plot. IIRC,  .plot makes ascii art graphs.